# java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.Serializable

Tags: scala, serialization

I am using scala.Serializable, but when i invoke String.asInstanceOf[Serializable], **class cast exception** is thrown. Here is my code, pretty simple.

```
arguments.map(_.asInstanceOf[Serializable])
```

Yes, arguments is array of string of course

I am run the application with scala-ide for eclipse with eclipse 3.7 and scala 2.9.0-1

**looking into this documentation [scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Serializable.html)**

The Problem now is "what is the typical use case of scala.Serializable"

Comment: So Kipton's answer shows how to make this work. But I can't think of any situation where it's a useful thing to do. Whatever you're trying to do, there's likely a better way to do it.

Comment: Hi Jilen, you linked the ScalaDoc for the trait `scala.Serializable`. But `java.lang.String` (which you will not find in the ScalaDoc) actually inherits `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But... what is scala.Serializable intend for...It cannot event serialize a string.

Comment: According to the ScalaDoc you linked, it's for defining your own classes that are serializable on all Scala platforms (currently Java and .NET).

Comment: Scala doesn't have its own cross-platform IO libraries yet. So I guess `scala.Serializable` is a placeholder for when they come. In any case, you haven't really described what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because java.lang.String does not implement scala.Serializable.  There are no dependencies from Java to Scala.

I think you'll find you don't need any cast, as java.lang.String does implement java.io.Serializable, but perhaps the context you omitted would make that clear.

Answer (score 10):

To add to what Ricky Clarkson said, this works

```
scala> "hi".asInstanceOf[java.io.Serializable]
res7: java.io.Serializable = hi
```

but this doesn't,

```
scala> "hi".asInstanceOf[scala.Serializable]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.Serializable
...
```

Without qualification, `Serializable` in Scala refers to `scala.Serializable`. Note that strings in Scala are of type `java.lang.String`; they are "native" to the JVM and don't know about Scala. According to the [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Serializable), the Scala serializable trait exists for cross platform compatibility (Java and .NET). If you're just on the JVM, then `java.io.Serializable` should be sufficient.